# Debug iOS push notifications in Cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to set up push notifications for iOS in a corber (cordova) Ember app with Pushbots. I am really struggling with this and how to debug; I think the problem is with provisioning but am stumped how to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have set up signing certificates and a provisioning profile in the Apple developer centre. My app is compiled using `xcodebuild` in a CI pipeline. I have checked:

- The expected code signing identity and provisioning profile are used in the build.
- My entitlements file includes `<key>aps-environment</key><string>production</string>`
- Integration of the app is done with Pushbots, and initialisation of this is being called as expected (https://www.pushbots.help/install-pushbots-in-your-app-or-website/ios/the-pushbots-part-integrating-pushbots-sdk-into-your-ios-project)

Crucially I can upload my app to the App store and TestFlight builds work successfully. However I do not get a prompt to allow notifications when I install the app, and the app does not appear in Settings > Notifications.

I would really appreciate any pointers where to start debugging this! Many thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: No - still completely stumped!